# Подключение к Ldap-серверу на php

Tags: php, ldap

Ребят нужно с помощью php подключиться к Ldap-серверу в локальной сети и вывести все что там есть, вопрос вывода я решу, а вот как подключиться в локальной сети на php я не знаю, направьте на путь истинный пожалуйста))

Comment: сокеты... И в локали, и в глобали

Answer (score 0):

Направляю на истинный путь - чтение документации  http://php.net/manual/ru/ldap.examples-basic.php